# En MySQL cuando doy el punto y coma ; me aparece los símbolos '> y no me deja seguir trabajando, tampoco me aparece error, ¿qué debo hacer?

Tags: mysql

MySQL cuando doy el punto y coma ; me aparece los símbolos '> y no me deja seguir trabajando, tampoco me aparece error, no me recibe ningún comando, ni siquiera exit tampoco quit, por lo tanto, me quedo en la pantalla eternamente y solo me deja salir bruscamente pulsando en la X para cerrar la ventana, entonces debo volver a entrar con las credenciales para poder seguir trabajando ¿qué debo hacer?

Comment: por favor mira [ask]... en donde escribis? mysql es una base de datos, o sea que estas usando una ide o algo para conectarte a la misma. Probaste conectarte de otra forma a ver si el problema es tu ide? asi como esta, no hay mucho para responderte...

Comment: Teclea `\s` seguido de un *Enter*  y después teclea lo que aparece en *Using delimiter* seguido de otro *Enter*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo más probable es que estés trabajando sobre la consola de MySql y tengas presionada la tecla ctrl.  Te recomiendo que instales XAMPP o en su defecto MySQL Workbench. Te ayudará a manejar mejor la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Cómo podría tu respuesta ayudar a quien trabaja en un Servidor sin UI, por ejemplo (aunque claramente no es el caso del OP) ? Te invito a leer [answer]. En lo futuro te recomiendo que evites responder preguntas mal formuladas o que crecen de detalles suficientes como para dar una respuesta única. En este caso también le pueden recomendar usar `phpMyAdmin` o `Toad` o cualquier otro programa con UI. Sin embargo, esa no es una respuesta a un problema que no queda claro en la pregunta. Saludos